# twin.macro preflight styles differ from tailwind preflight

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, emotion, css-in-js

According to my research and `twin.examples` repo for `Next.js`, `twin.macro` recommends adding their preflight component, which they name `<GlobalStyles />`. They often alias it to `<BaseStyles />` because, for my understanding, the component exports a set of preflight styles that resets browser behavior to sane defaults. This recommended component, allegedly contains the same styling as `tailwind/base.css` (aka `@tailwind base;` in CSS files), plus some keyframes to help with animations provided by twin.

However, when I use this component instead of the preflights provided by my current TailwindCSS 3.2 all my classNames are ignored and styled-components break. Note that I am using `twin.macro v3` latest release candidate, because previous versions are not compatible with TailwindCSS 3.

Can anybody explain this, point me to a place where I can learn a workaround, or knows a workaround?

I have an open discussion on the official repo with more context (and screenshots) but no answer just yet. You can check it out here: https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro/discussions/719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find an answer by trial and error and by waiting out a response on the link above. The solution to the problem was to use the `tw` and `css` component properties instead of `className` (as implicitly described in `twin.macro` docs).

Also, if you are using other CSS imports like `@tailwind/layers` and `@tailwind/utilities`, etc..., you do not need to import these anywhere as long as you are importing `twin.macro#GlobalStyles` component, as exemplified in the docs.

Hope this helps someone! :)